# JavaScript Child Theme / Parent Theme Link

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on building [this site](http://dennistodd.canny-creative.com) and have an issue with the nav/floating nav section which I can fix within the parent theme. However, I'm struggling to get it all linked up in the child theme.

The JS itself is located in `/javascript/gdlr-script.js` with it being hooked in via `/include/gdlr-include-script.php` - so naturally, I've made a carbon copy of the structure in my child theme and changed the include file to;

```
// include theme script / style
$array['script']['gdlr-script'] = GDLR_PATH . '/flawless-v1-15-child/javascript/gdlr-script.js';
```

Enqueue:

```
// register the necessary script depends on the condition of that page
if( !is_admin() ){ 
    add_filter('gdlr_enqueue_scripts', 'gdlr_regiser_use_script'); 
}

if( !function_exists('gdlr_regiser_use_script') ){
    function gdlr_regiser_use_script($array){   
        global $theme_option, $gdlr_post_option;
```

Naturally, that points to the JS file I want it to use, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something here?

I can fix it within the parent theme, so I know my code is right pertaining to the JS, as I've had it working. Something just doesn't add up. Is there a reason that this wouldn't overwrite the parent folders?

Comment: It's not clear how you're enqueuing the scripts. Better to see the relevant theme code before checking the site.

Comment: I think I've added the enqueue?

Comment: [Google tells me](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%2Fgdlr-script.js) that you're talking about a [ThemeForest premium theme](http://themeforest.net/item/flawless-responsive-multipurpose-wp-theme/6526764). We don't have access to this code and need a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or you'll have to ask for support over there. Please, head to the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I've fixed it. Just needed to sleep apparently. Using this dequeue/enqueue method from Stack Exchange.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26822/how-to-override-javascript-files-in-child-theme